# Get the last 4 characters of a string

Tags: python, string

I have the following string: `"aaaabbbb"`

How can I get the last four characters and store them in a string using Python?

Answer (score 1054, accepted):

Like this:

```
>>> mystr = "abcdefghijkl"
>>> mystr[-4:]
'ijkl'
```

This [slices](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) the string's last 4 characters. The -4 starts the range from the string's end. A modified expression with `[:-4]` removes the same 4 characters from the end of the string:

```
>>> mystr[:-4]
'abcdefgh'
```

For more information on slicing see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/8117067).

Comment: I remember it like this, -4 is short hand for (length - 4)

Comment: +1, this is pure gold... There I was faffing around with `len(str(p)) - str(p[len(str(reversed(str(p))).split(' ', 1))[0])], len(str(p)), 2)` to get the last *n* letters of `p` based on the first space. Useless and doesn't even work.

Comment: Remember the `:`, otherwise you'll just get the 4th last character!

Answer (score 86):

```
str = "aaaaabbbb"
newstr = str[-4:]
```

See : http://codepad.org/S3zjnKoD

Comment: Do no use built in names such as str as a variable name. Use `string` instead.